# Can you remove a 'Personal Workshop' 'Power Counter' during an encounter with ICE?

Tags: android-netrunner

[Personal Workshop](http://netrunner.randomblink.com/cyberexodus/personalworkshop)

> When your turn begins, remove 1 power counter from a hosted card.
>   When there are no power counters left on a hosted card, install it, ignoring all costs.
>
> **[Click]**: Host a program or a piece of hardware from your grip on Personal Workshop and place power counters on it equal to its install cost.
>
> 1 **[credit]**: Remove 1 power counter from a hosted card.

---

1. I am the Runner.
2. I have nothing but **Personal Workshop** installed.
3. I have 20 **[credits]**.
4. I have 1 of each icebreaker hosted on **Personal Workshop** with a variable amount of power counters on them.
5. I start a run.
6. The Corp rezzes an ICE of type X.
7. I pay Y **[credits]** to remove all the remaining Y **[power counters]** from icebreaker Z.
8. Icebreaker Z is now installed per the last listed ability on **Personal Workshop.**

> 1 [credit] : Remove 1 [power counter] from a hosted card.

1. I can continue my run, but now with the icebreaker I need installed.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: This is actually a way that Personal Workshop was used a lot. People would Stimhack for the 9 credits and spend at least part of them on workshop installs, particularly in Haley, to get her from hand install off mid run (a lot of Egrets installed that way), though these installs in Haley were also done on corp turn. This is no longer viable though, due to Personal Workshop rotating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Personal Workshop allows you to install programs/hardware during a run. You have already paid the click to host them though, so all its really doing is allowing you to defer payment until they are needed.

This does allow you to install a Femme Fatale after the corp rezzes and Ice, targeting that Ice for the special bypass, and then bypass the Ice as you encounter it that turn. Or to install a parasite on an Ice after its rezzed, and then immediately lower its Strength to 0 so it gets trashed using Wyrm/Datasuckers when you encounter it.